# How to deploy react app with apollo cient and apollo-server backend on local network

Tags: reactjs, deployment, apollo, apollo-client, pm2

I have been banging my head this few days now, on how to deploy a react app with apollo server at the back end in a local network, with a windows server, the client wants the react app with the back end which is apollo server and monggodb to run on their local network, which is typing the local ip address on the server on their web browser like 192.168.1.129 with the app will run. I cant deploy it to heruko because it will initial additional cost for the client, I had been searching for tutorials this past few days, and found reverse proxy on IIS, NGINX, PM2, but no clear step by step detailed instruction on how to do about it, any help would be highly appreciated... or else 2 months of code will go down the drain,,

Answer (score 0):

Caveat:
I'm not familiar with Apollo and the following is just a recommendation based on following Apollo's Getting Started Guide (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/)

1. Run Apollo in the server via `node index.js`. This will bind to http://localhost:4000 (or could be different, just look at what the CLI says)

> Running it this way, I think runs the code in Development mode. You might want to have this run in Production mode. I think using `NODE_ENV=production node index.js` would do it, but I'm not completely sure.

2. Reverse proxy in IIS (since you're on Windows) so that going to the IP address of the server, proxies port 80 to localhost:4000. In Nginx, it would something be like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

3. Figure out how to convert the running of Apollo as a start up & background process. Sadly, I'm not familiar with Windows server administration, but in Ubuntu this would be via `systemd` service scripts.

Hopefully, that's enough for you to go on.